# Proving trigonometric identity without using trigonometry

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove the next identity, without using trigonometric identities:
$$\cos 3x = \cos^3x-3\cos x \sin^2 x $$
It's part of linear algebra homework.

Comment: What exactly counts as “trigonometric identities”? This task seems almost unsolvable by definition...

Comment: De Moivre's Theorem do require trigonometric identities to prove.  How about using Taylor series expansion: $$\cos^3 x-3\cos x \sin^2 x=\left( 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots \right)^3-3\left( 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots \right)\left( x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\ldots \right)^2$$

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still not there...

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Use complex numbers:
$$(\cos x+ i\sin x)^3=(e^{ix})^3=(e^{3ix})=\cos 3x+i \sin 3x.$$
Now expand the cubic on the left and then separate real and complex parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't been introduced to complex numbers yet, note that $3x = 2x + x$, and use the sum of angles formula:
$$
\cos(3x) = \cos(2x + x) = \cos(2x)\cos(x) - \sin(2x)\sin(x)
$$
Now use the sum of angles formula again (the double angle formula) to get expressions for $\cos(2x)$ and $\sin(2x)$, and insert those.

Comment: Of course I've been introduced to complex numbers, that's part of linear algebra homework regarding complex numbers. Anyway, they didn't want us to use those trigonometric identities. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Shalom.I Well, you never know whether a concept has been introduced or not, do you? This could've been a question in last year of high school in my country, and they don't have complex numbers on their curriculum. That being said, I missed your "without using trigonometric identities", so this is clearly not what was intended.